# How to compile and run a Netbeans java project in command line without jar file?

Tags: java, netbeans, command-line, jar, netbeans-8

I have a java Netbeans project having directory structure:

```
EMailQueue/
|-build/
|-classes/
|-mailqueue/
|-nbproject/
|-src/
 |-mailqueue/
|-dist/
 |-lib/
|-build.xml
|-maifest.mf
```

`build/classes/mailqueue/` directory consists of all the classes compiled from all the .java files in `src/mailqueue/` directory and `dist/lib/` consists of all the .jar files (except JDK) imported in the application's files.

I want to know, how to run this application without using the jar file present inside the `dist/` directory.

Also I want to know if I do not have classes files with me then how to compile .java files in `src/mailqueue/` to generate class files in `build/classes/mailqueue/` directory.

PS: Please give the exact command to run in terminal and optionally any explanation.

Answer (score 4):

To compile Netbeans project You need to call Apache ant tool and pass them your build script file thorough -f parameter like this

> > ant -f ../apppath/build.xml

this will do full project with building jar file.
If You look at build.xml file You will see that it's only points to ./nbproject/build-impl.xml file where all required actions are actually defined.
Once no parameters passed to ant it calls default target

> > ```
> > <target depends="test,jar,javadoc" description="Build and test whole project." name="default"/>
> > ```

You see that this task depends of three other. Most interest is 'jar' target.

Look at this target - it depends of other 'compile' target

To call this target directly You need to pass this target to ant tool

> > ant -f ../apppath/build.xml compile

This will compile project but not to pack them to jar

> > ant -f ../apppath/build.xml run

will compile project and run main class

Hope this helps.

To compile Your code with pure java You need at first to run java compler in folder with all java files i.e call javac. 
javac -cp {path to all java library files and external class files}  *.java
Once You have all compiled with no errors run java same way and pass them Your main class name You want to run
java -cp {path to all java library files and external class files} ClassName

Comment: If I have given this files to someone who does't know about netbeans, these commands would do? In short Apache ant is to be installed before it could be used in command line? I tried this I I got a message that 'ant' is a recognised command.

Comment: Yes. Ant is need to be installed.

Comment: Is there no way to compile/run the application using javac/java command?

Comment: To compile Your code with pure java You need to run java compller in folder with all java files

Comment: @Marks even I know that, but it didn't worked that is why I asked the question